# Group by in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I'm currently converting some of my older T-SQL scripts for use in BigQuery - I've got a problem, though - It seems that for every non-aggregated field used in the SELECT, even as part of a CASE WHEN, have to be declared in the GROUP BY - which I don't want! This didn't seem to be an issue in T-SQL, is there anyway around this so I only have to group on the first three fields?

i.e. without:

```
ss.UK_Sample_Size,
ss.Study_Design_Type
```

Code attached:

```
SELECT
  LCRN AS [OrganisationName],
  os.populationinmillions as [population_in_millions],
  os.percentageoftotalpopulation as [percentage_of_total_population],
  SUM([recruitmentcount]) as recruitment,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ss.UK_Sample_Size >=10000 then sum(recruitmentcount) end) as Band1_Recruitment,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Observational' or ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Not Specified') and (ss.UK_Sample_Size < 10000 or ss.UK_Sample_Size is null) then sum(recruitmentcount) end) as Observational_Recruitment,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Interventional' or ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Both') and (ss.UK_Sample_Size < 10000 or ss.UK_Sample_Size is null) then sum(recruitmentcount) end) as Interventional_Recruitment

   // PROBLEM
   // 1. We dont want to group on study design type and uk sample size
   // 2. We want to select by a date value held as a variable

FROM
 [mydataset.BQ_Upload_ALL] AS bq
JOIN
 [mydataset.Study_Summary] AS ss
ON
 bq.studyid = ss.study_id
JOIN
 [mydataset.ONS_Population] as os
ON
 bq.LCRN = os.LocalNetwork
WHERE
 recruitmentactivitydate_fy = '2016/17'
GROUP BY
 [OrganisationName],
 [population_in_millions],
 [percentage_of_total_population],
 ss.UK_Sample_Size,
 ss.Study_Design_Type 
ORDER BY 
 recruitment DESC;
```

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below (moved qualification logic for Band/Observational/Interventional inside subselect)

```
SELECT
  [OrganisationName],
  [population_in_millions],
  [percentage_of_total_population],
  SUM([recruitmentcount]) AS recruitment,
  SUM(Band1_recruitmentcount) AS Band1_Recruitment,
  SUM(Observational_recruitmentcount) AS Observational_Recruitment,
  SUM(Interventional_recruitmentcount) AS Interventional_Recruitment
FROM (
  SELECT 
    LCRN AS [OrganisationName],
    os.populationinmillions AS [population_in_millions],
    os.percentageoftotalpopulation AS [percentage_of_total_population],
    recruitmentcount,
    CASE WHEN ss.UK_Sample_Size >= 10000 THEN recruitmentcount ELSE 0 END AS Band1_recruitmentcount, 
    CASE WHEN (ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Observational' OR ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Not Specified') AND (ss.UK_Sample_Size < 10000 OR ss.UK_Sample_Size IS NULL) THEN recruitmentcount ELSE 0 END AS Observational_recruitmentcount,
    CASE WHEN (ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Interventional' OR ss.Study_Design_Type = 'Both') AND (ss.UK_Sample_Size < 10000 OR ss.UK_Sample_Size IS NULL) THEN recruitmentcount ELSE 0 END AS Interventional_recruitmentcount
  FROM
   [mydataset.BQ_Upload_ALL] AS bq
  JOIN
   [mydataset.Study_Summary] AS ss
  ON
   bq.studyid = ss.study_id
  JOIN
   [mydataset.ONS_Population] AS os
  ON
   bq.LCRN = os.LocalNetwork
  WHERE
   recruitmentactivitydate_fy = '2016/17'
)
GROUP BY
  [OrganisationName],
  [population_in_millions],
  [percentage_of_total_population],
ORDER BY recruitment DESC
```